# Dell R610 Cannot create VD with disks

Tags: dell

I'm having an issue adding some additional drives to my Dell R610.

I first tried using a few HGST 600gb sas drives model: HUC106060css600
I then tried to use a few HGST 600gb sas drives model: HUC109060CSS600

The issue I am having seems strange to me but I am somewhat new to this. I can see the drives in the PERC and attempt to create a VD with them. I have tried a few separate and even a few in RAID 0 and they always fail to create the VD and I than get the amber flashes indicating a disk fault.

I received this server in January of 2018 and all firmware and drivers were updated at that time.

Am I perhaps doing something incorrect? I figure it might be due to not using certified disks, and certainly I can try to pick some of those up but want to make sure it's not related to soothing else.

Thanks,

Comment: Seems it might not be a server issue with blocking drives as I was able to add a random sata drive I had laying around.. Perhaps there drives are formatted differently; looking around I seen mentions of some drives not being 512 sector size.. I'm just unsure how to test that without being able to add it it a VD..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is with the firmware on these specific drives. Attempting to write anything to them and sometimes even just a read on them results in a fault.

I have since tested other non-certified drives; including consumer grade sata drives. They worked just fine.

I have not yet messed with trying to flash a different firmware on them but if I do in the future I'll update here.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is most probably caused by the non-certified disk and the Virtual Disk is failing to create because of this issue.

You have to install the OS (Windows) and then install Dell OpenManage server administrator and try to create VD from the GUI.

By the way, make sure that you have installed the latest firmware (especially for the RAID controller).

Comment: No. You can't install Windows on the server without first creating a VD in the RAID controller config utility. Without first creating the VD there's nothing to install Windows on.

Comment: @joeqwerty Is correct, you cannot install any OS if you cannot create a VD with the drives. Outside of the raid controller the drive will not be seen at all until they are added to a VD from my experience.